# one-to-many and saving records

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am creating a simple CMS and I have a set of templates, each template can have multiple blocks within them.

So I have a one-to-many relationship between the templates and blocks (1 template can have many blocks)

So, when I create a block, it has a drop down of the templates that I can associate the block to using `sfDoctrineChoice` widget.

In my BlockForm.class.php

`new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model' => 'Template', 'multiple'=>true, 'expanded'=>false))`

My schema is:

```
Template:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    name:
      type: varchar(255)
    layout:
      type: text
  relations:
   Block:
     class: Block
     local: id
     foreign: template_id
     type: many
     foreignType: one
     alias: Block
     foreignAlias: Template
Block:  
  columns:  
    template_id:  { type: integer(8), notnull: true }  
    content:      { type: clob, notnull: true  }
```

The problem comes when I try to save the choices. It gives me a:

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` when I select 2 or more templates or when I select 1 option:

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.`block`, CONSTRAINT`block_template_id_template_id`FOREIGN KEY (`template_id`) REFERENCES`template`(`id`))`

Is my schema correct to do what I'm looking to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Build the database tables the way you want them first.
2. Rename your old schema.yml to schema-20110610.yml
3. Run task symfony doctrine:build-schema
4. Take a look at the new schema.yml file you created. It may give you an idea of what you are doing wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You must add foreign key constraint. onDelete and onUpdate.

```
Template:
  actAs:
    Timestampable: ~
  columns:
    name:
      type: varchar(255)
    layout:
      type: text

Block:  
  columns:  
    template_id:  { type: integer(8), notnull: true }  
    content:      { type: clob, notnull: true  }
  relations:
    Template:
      local: template_id
      foreign: id
      foreignAlias: Blocks
```

Comment: That hasn't worked either. When I select one option, I now get: `Array to string conversion ....` which is odd. i also still get the `Integrity constraint` when selecting 2 or more templates

Comment: That still gives me the above intetgrity violation problem.